# GCM Broadcast Receiver not triggering

Tags: java, php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I have looked at several questions on this site and none seem to be able to answer my question so hopefully someone can help with this. Currently for some reason when I send a message through from the PHP Website, my app doesn't receive the message. I have tried placing Log.d's in the lines of code but it doesn't appear as well. Can someone help to see if something has gone wrong?

[UPDATE] This is the result when I send from the php website
{"multicast_id":5610818169388245295,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1460536959734990%40ad5721f9fd7ecd"}]}

My manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.amosang.pushtest" >

<!-- GCM Permissions - Start here  -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.amosang.pushtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.amosang.pushtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
    </activity>
</application>

<receiver
    android:name=".GCMBroadcastReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="com.example.amosang.pushtest" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name=".GCMNotificationIntentService">
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
</service>

</manifest>
```

My Broadcast Receiver

```
public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    Log.d("TESTTEST", "TEST");
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
}
```

My intent service

```
public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService{


//set ID for the notification, so it can be updated
public static final int notifyID = 9001;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
    super("GCM Intent Service");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
    Log.d("RECEIVEDMESSAGE", messageType);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                    + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Message Received from Google GCM Server:nn"
                    + extras.get(AppConstants.MSG_KEY));
        }
    }

    GCMBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void sendNotification(String msg){

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    Log.d("RECEIVEDPT2",msg);
    resultIntent.putExtra("msg", msg);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,resultIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setContentTitle("Alert")
            .setContentTitle("You've received a new message");

    //Set pending intent
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    //Set vibration
    int defaults = 0;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    mNotifyBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
    // Set the content for Notification
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentText("You have new notifications");
    // Set autocancel
    mNotifyBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    // Post a notification
    mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, mNotifyBuilder.build());

}
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Add this `intent-filter` for your service in the manifest file: `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            </intent-filter>`

Comment: I have this already. Where do I place this?

Comment: Inside the `<service>` tag

Comment: It still doesn't work. Do i need to place category in there too?

Comment: No. Also you have `<uses-permission android:name="com.example.amosang.pushtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />` two times on your manifest file. Remove it from one place.

Comment: I updated my manifest in the question too however it still doesn't work. I've even checked the logs

Comment: Which android version you are using ? For older you need "<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />"

Comment: I haven't set a targetsdk yet. I'm developing for lollipop atm. So instead of using c2dm message i use registration?

Comment: The website I used had the same code. I must be missing something..

Comment: I have tried working on this and nothing so far.